# How to get url which opens modal window

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With beautifulsoup I have access to the content of this web page: https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart

In this webpage, if you make click over a point in the field you've got data from the player and the shot. You can see this information in this image:

[image]

If I inspect this image with Firefox, for example, I've got this code in the console:

[image]

As you can see we've got the information which is showed in the modal window.

Therefore, I would like how to get the URL of this content that appears in the modal window or how to web scrape this content using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Headless browser is more applicable here

Comment: @emptyhua Hi!!! Can you explain it a little more or put any example, please. I'm newbie with WebScraping.

Comment: you can run headless browser like `selenium` to visit the web page, simulate a user's click action, then get the url throw python API

Comment: @emptyhua Ok, I understand right now. I'll try to do it.

Comment: Is it just the url you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL. You can use this example to load the data and creating a dataframe with scoring stats:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart"
api_url = "https://livecache.sportresult.com/node/db/FIBASTATS_PROD/{event_id}_GAME_{rsc}_JSON.json?s=unknown&t=0"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text

event_id = re.search(r"setEventId\('(.*?)'\)", html_doc).group(1)
rsc = re.search(r"rsc: '(.*?)'", html_doc).group(1)
data = requests.get(api_url.format(event_id=event_id, rsc=rsc)).json()

# print full data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print basic table:
df = pd.json_normalize(data["content"]["full"]["ScoreList"]).explode("Items")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("Items").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Period  AC        C1 Code  SA  SB  Score     Team   Time
0     Q1  P2  P_204187    2   0   2    0-2  T_65512  09:00
0     Q1  P3  P_151112    5   0   5    0-5  T_65512  07:48
0     Q1  P2  P_174621    7   0   7    0-7  T_65512  06:40
0     Q1  P3  P_204187   10   0  10   0-10  T_65512  06:15
0     Q1  P2  P_174621   12   0  12   0-12  T_65512  05:41
0     Q1  P2  P_160522   10   2  12   2-12   T_9998  03:57
0     Q1  P2  P_195803    8   4  12   4-12   T_9998  03:29
0     Q1  P2  P_204187   10   4  14   4-14  T_65512  02:55
0     Q1  P2  P_174621   12   4  16   4-16  T_65512  01:24
0     Q1  P3  P_137210    9   7  16   7-16   T_9998  00:57
0     Q1  P2  P_160420   11   7  18   7-18  T_65512  00:33
0     Q1  FT  P_174621   12   7  19   7-19  T_65512  00:11
1     Q2  P2  P_219548   14   7  21   7-21  T_65512  09:26
1     Q2  P3  P_204187   17   7  24   7-24  T_65512  08:30
1     Q2  P2  P_219548   19   7  26   7-26  T_65512  08:05

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!! I appreciated too much your help!!! Thanks @Andrej Kesely!!! This is very useful to me but I need a mix of your solution and the solution proposed by emptyhua. With the help of both of you I will make my development finally!!! The reason why I need a mix is due to a need an "x" and a "y" for each shot that you can find in the code of this page: https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart.  Thanks a lot for your appreciated help to both of you!!!